# Por que a diminuição da máscara de sub rede dobra o tamanho da rede original?

Tags: redes, ip

Lendo sobre protocolo IP e sobre endereçamento de rede, não entendi porque a "**diminuição**" do tamanho da mascara de sub rede em 1 *bit*, gera um "**aumento**" do tamanho da rede.

Eu entendi o motivo do aumento, mas não o fato da diminuição de 1 *bit* gerar o dobro do aumento.

O inverso também é verdadeiro segundo a fonte do [ppgia](https://www.ppgia.pucpr.br/~jamhour/Download/pub/RSS/POS_RSS/ApostilaProtocoloIP.pdf).
[image: porque]

> **Afirmação do autor**
>
> > O processo de agrupamento de subredes é igualmente simples. Cada vez que diminuímos o tamanho da máscara de subrede em 1 bit, criamos um super-rede que tem o dobro do tamanho da rede original. Na prática, o conceito de super-redes é bastante útil para diminuir o número de entradas nas tabelas de roteamento dos roteadores na Internet.

fonte: [ppgia.pucpr.br](https://www.ppgia.pucpr.br/~jamhour/Download/pub/RSS/POS_RSS/ApostilaProtocoloIP.pdf)

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque redes, até o dado não faz parte do escopo do site. Não sou contra, desde que não seja procaria, acredito que até faça bem a comunidade, mas até agora não é permitido.

Comment: Ok, agradeço o feedback.

Comment: @Stormwind eu tendo a concordar, porém acho que esta pergunta pode ser considerada dentro do escopo do site. [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) tem uma lista com cinco itens, acho que esta pergunta se encaixa pelo menos nos dois últimos.

Comment: Veremos como é o desenrolar dessa pergunta e suas respostas @Renan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A máscara é feita para separar a parte da rede da parte do host.

Os `bits` com valor `1` representam a parte da rede, enquanto os `bits` com valor `0` representam a parte do host. E são esses `bits` com valor `0` que são usados para *gerar* os IPs únicos dos hosts.

Com isso vale explicar a notação /24, /25, etc. Essa notação conta o número de `1` consecutivos na máscara.

O fato de aumentar/diminuir 1 `bit` diminuir pela metade/dobrar o tamanho da rede é natural da representação binária. O tamanho da rede é dado por `2^(32-mascara)`.

Um exemplo ilustrativo.

```
Mascara:    255.255.255.0 = 24  11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
```

Logo temos os 8 últimos `bits` disponíveis, 2^8 = 256 IPs.

Se utilizarmos a mascara /23:

```
Mascara:    255.255.254.0 = 23  11111111.11111111.1111111 0.00000000
```

Agora temos os 9 últimos `bits` disponíveis. 2^9 = 512 IPs. O dobro do anterior.

Comment: Então você "diminui" a quantidade representativa da mascara para "aumentar" na quantidade que representa o host, agradeço por responder,  esse numero /23 ou /22 no fim do ip ficou bem mais claro agora.